# dynamic text length limit based on div width

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a div which will be having dynamic width, based on the width I have to restrict the content within that div,I have created a filter which will cut the text and append "..." to the end of the string, but the issue is how we can assign the limit based on the dynamic width size

my code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2aLmbjwz/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="test" ng-style="myStyle">{{value  | splice:12:' ...'}}</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myStyle={};
        $scope.myStyle.width = "150px";
        $scope.value= "My value is anythinggggggggggggggggg";
})

.filter('splice', function () {
        return function (value, max, tail) {
            if (!value) return '';
            max = parseInt(max, 10);
            if (!max) return value;
            if (value.length <= max) return value;
            value = value.substr(0, max);
            return value + (tail || ' …');
        };
});
```

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/pgc4pqn2/, see if it satisfies your need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried with a different appraoch for your problem. See if it helps:

Instead of passing the `limit` to the filter, am passing the `width` of the element.

```
<div class="test" ng-style="myStyle">{{value  | splice:myStyle.width:' ...'}}</div>
```

Now inside your filter:

```
       function (value, max, tail) {
            if(isNaN(max))
                max = parseInt(max.slice(0,-2),10)/12;
            if (!value) return '';
            max = parseInt(max, 10);
            // rest of your code
```

Am checking if it's a string. In case its a string, assuming you're passing `width` in format of `150px`. So slicing the `px` from the string. we've `150` now.

Now taking the least font size of 8 and dividing it by 8. So now the limit will be based on the width of the element.

You can reuse the same `filter` by passing the width as well as passing the limit directly. It will suit for both the scenarios now.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/pgc4pqn2/)

> Updated Answer

I've been looking at different solutions. As you've mentioned in comments that the font-size may vary. I guess better we go with simple CSS based approach in that case using `text-overflow`.

```
.test {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Now whatever may be the font-size, the text will always be clipped. Now in whichever elements you want to have this feature, add specific css class `clip-text`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/ugyvrhmc/2/)**

Comment: if I assign width as 150px the box is partially filling not completly

Comment: Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/pgc4pqn2/3/ , You've padding-right to that box, that's the reason why you see space left

Comment: you have made it to 8 instead of 10, say if the font size is 20 this will not work right

Comment: Yes, if the font-size going to vary then it will fail.  In that case we need to consider font-size, padding, etc to make it fit

Comment: I feel doing it via `css` would be a better solution in that case. Using `text-overflow`

Comment: `element[0].offsetWidth` value may differ between different browsers right, In chrome I am getting 12a and in firefox 544, do we have any other alternate way

Comment: You can determine width using offsetWidth and clientWidth properties. Else must use jquery